# how to append text in hdfs file with java api?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I want create code java to save or append my text content to file in hdfs, but it returns Error, the flowing is my java code to append my text content to my file in `HDFS` system:

```
public class FileAppend {

    public static final String uri = "hdfs://192.168.3.152:9000/work/log.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

         String content = "bonjour";
         Configuration conf = new Configuration();


         FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);

         boolean flag = Boolean.getBoolean(fs.getConf().get("dfs.support.append"));

         System.out.println("dfs.support.append is set to be " + flag);

         if (true) {

         FSDataOutputStream fsout = fs.append(new Path(uri));

         PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fsout);

         writer.append(content);

         writer.close();

         } else {

         System.err.println("please set the dfs.support.append to be true");

         }

         fs.close();
```

and the code my return thus erreur:

```
juil. 04, 2016 10:01:32 AM org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection handleConnectionFailure
INFOS: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.3.152:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).
juil. 04, 2016 10:01:33 AM org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection handleConnectionFailure
INFOS: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.3.152:9000. Already tried 1 time(s).
juil. 04, 2016 10:01:34 AM org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection handleConnectionFailure
INFOS: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.3.152:9000. Already tried 2 time(s).
juil. 04, 2016 10:01:35 AM org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection handleConnectionFailure
INFOS: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.3.152:9000. Already tried 3 time(s).
```

Comment: what hadoop version using for your server and clients, it sounds to me like version mismatch

Comment: i used 2.6.0 version

Comment: that's for both server and hbase client program?  Are you executing the program in cluster or your windows desktop with eclipse? if you are executing from the eclipse client with some jars in class path then make sure  that you jars version is same as cluster you are trying to connect. due version mismatch these kind of obscure errors might pop-up. we got these kind of errors when we pulled these jars from mvn repository rather than cluster. Can you pls. cross check!